# Find a group $H$ of permutations such that $U(10) \cong H$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-isomorphism

Find a group $H$ of permutations such that $U(10) \cong H$

My idea:

since $U(1)=\{1,3,7,9\}$

since order of 1 is 1

order of 3 is 4

order of 7 is 4

order of 9 is 2

so we have to find a permutation H with four elements and order of these elements are equal order of the elements of U(10)

is this idea is right

Comment: You can always use Cayley's theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley's_theorem

Comment: Do you realize that $U(10) \simeq \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$? This will help you to understand what kind of permutation group you require.

Comment: @krish ..yes i know that $U(10) \simeq \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ but still finding exapme i am facing difficuties

Comment: Since the group is cyclic and of order four, try to look at permutations in some $S_n$ of order four. You can guess it easily. :)

Comment: Hint: for any $g \in U(10)$, can you think of a bijective map $U(10) \to U(10)$ induced by $g$?